# Error when import a .cypher file in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to import a **.cypher** `dump` file  so that in can have structure with relationship and data into my **neo4j database**,when i export everything goes fine,but when tryging to import i got the following error :

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'B': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"BEGIN"
 ^
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'B': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
 "BEGIN" ^
```

Here is the dump cypher file structure :

```
BEGIN
CREATE (:`ContentType`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`created_at`:"2019-05-14 09:01:15", `description`:"Ceci est un lien", `name`:"Link", `slug`:"link", `type`:"LINK", `updated_at`:"2019-05-14 10:47:21", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2124});
CREATE (:`ContentType`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`created_at`:"2019-05-14 09:02:35", `description`:"Ceci est un fichier", `name`:"File", `slug`:"file", `type`:"FILE", `updated_at`:"2019-05-14 10:47:46", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2144});
CREATE (:`ContentType`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`created_at`:"2019-05-14 09:04:08", `description`:"Ceci est un evènement", `name`:"Event", `slug`:"event", `type`:"EVENT", `updated_at`:"2019-05-14 10:48:01", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164});
CREATE (:`ContentType`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`created_at`:"2019-05-14 09:04:08", `description`:"Ceci est un evènement", `name`:"Event", `slug`:"event", `type`:"EVENT", `updated_at`:"2019-05-14 10:48:01", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164});
CREATE (:`ContentType`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`created_at`:"2019-05-14 09:04:08", `description`:"Ceci est un evènement", `name`:"Event", `slug`:"event", `type`:"EVENT", `updated_at`:"2019-05-14 10:48:01", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164});
CREATE (:`CustomField`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`field_name`:"input_link", `field_order`:1, `field_type`:"string", `updated_at`:"2019-05-16 10:48:26", `validation_rules`:"required|url", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2225});
CREATE (:`CustomField`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`field_name`:"input_file", `field_order`:1, `field_type`:"string", `updated_at`:"2019-05-16 10:48:08", `validation_rules`:"required|max:10000|mimes:doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,pdf,png,jpg,jpeg", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2226});
CREATE (:`CustomField`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`field_name`:"input_end_date", `field_order`:2, `field_type`:"string", `updated_at`:"2019-05-16 13:11:09", `validation_rules`:"required|date|after:input_start_date", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2229});
CREATE (:`CustomField`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`field_name`:"input_address", `field_order`:5, `field_type`:"string", `updated_at`:"2019-05-16 10:47:15", `validation_rules`:"required", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2228});
CREATE (:`CustomField`:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` {`field_name`:"input_start_date", `field_order`:1, `field_type`:"string", `updated_at`:"2019-05-16 13:10:26", `validation_rules`:"required|date|before:input_end_date", `UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2227});
COMMIT
BEGIN
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`) ASSERT node.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID` IS UNIQUE;
COMMIT
SCHEMA AWAIT
BEGIN
MATCH (n1:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2228}), (n2:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164}) CREATE (n1)-[r:`HAS_FIELD` {`created_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36", `updated_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36"}]->(n2);
MATCH (n1:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2226}), (n2:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2144}) CREATE (n1)-[r:`HAS_FIELD` {`created_at`:"2019-05-15 07:37:47", `updated_at`:"2019-05-15 07:37:47"}]->(n2);
MATCH (n1:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2225}), (n2:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2124}) CREATE (n1)-[r:`HAS_FIELD` {`created_at`:"2019-05-15 07:43:05", `updated_at`:"2019-05-15 07:43:05"}]->(n2);
MATCH (n1:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2227}), (n2:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164}) CREATE (n1)-[r:`HAS_FIELD` {`created_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36", `updated_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36"}]->(n2);
MATCH (n1:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2229}), (n2:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`{`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`:2164}) CREATE (n1)-[r:`HAS_FIELD` {`created_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36", `updated_at`:"2019-05-15 07:54:36"}]->(n2);
COMMIT
BEGIN
MATCH (n:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`)  WITH n LIMIT 20000 REMOVE n:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL` REMOVE n.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID`;
COMMIT
BEGIN
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (node:`UNIQUE IMPORT LABEL`) ASSERT node.`UNIQUE IMPORT ID` IS UNIQUE;
COMMIT
```

I've search in the internet,but most topic talks about importing **CSV files** ,not cypher.

In my database from where i've imported,here is the relashionship : `(ContentType)-[:HAS_FIELD]-(CustomField)`,and fields of `ContentType` are `type,name,description,slug` and `CustomField` fields are `field_name,display_name,field_type,field_order,validation_rules`.

Why does the import statement work when i paste the content of my dump file in noe4j and the run it?

Comment: Try removing `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`

Comment: The neo4j environment has many tools with overlapping capabilities. What tool did you use to "dump" to the file? And what exactly did you do in order to "dump file in noe4j and then run it"?

Comment: When i remove `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` i get the following error `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 18`